# How do you create a simple login screen in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication

I am making an app that uses a login screen I made. The input is this Text Field that you type in your username. How do I make it respond to different usernames? For example the username is UK. How do I make it respond to if it is or is not 'UK'? I am a complete beginner to Xcode so could you please walk me through the steps please?

I tried using this `if(Username!.text, isEqual: "Hello")` that I saw from a video, but an error pops up saying:

> '(String?, isEqual: String)' is not convertible to 'Bool'.

I have no idea what it means and how to get around it.

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var ftest: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Username: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet var Password: UITextField!

    @IBAction func SignIn(_ sender: Any) {
        if(Username!.text, isEqual: "Hello")
    }
    //this code above is the code I tried to do based on a video and it did not work.

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

I want it to print "Hi" or something. I just want it to react to:

1. If the username is 'UK' and
2. If the username is not 'UK'.

Comment: You're probably watching a video using objective c and trying to convert it to swift. If I remember correctly, before you had to do `string.isEqual(to: someOtherString)` because at one point, `string == someOtherString` was checking memory addresses and not the strings.  Now (for as long as I remember) you can use `==` on strings and it will check their contents.  
Also, your `if string == someOtherString` statement doesn't need to be wrapped in brackets `()` The only time you need to use brackets is to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score -1):

You can just simply use `==` as follow

```
@IBAction func SignIn(_ sender: Any) {
     if(Username!.text == "Hello" || Username!.text == "UK") {
          print("Hi")
     }
}
```

`||` means OR 
`&&` means AND

Hope this help!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in this way

```
 @IBAction func SignIn(_ sender: Any) {
    if Username!.text == "UK"
    {
     print("Hi")
    }
    else 
    {
    // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Moreover you can also use a variable to check whether a string contained in your textfield or not like this:

```
var Str = "UK"
     if Str.contains(self.Username!.text!) {
        print("Hi")
     }
```

**Extension way:**

```
extension String {
            func contains(find: String) -> Bool{
                return self.range(of: find) != nil
            }
        }

    var value = self.Username!.text // You can put value as of your textfield.text and then check

    print(value.contains("UK")) // true 
    print(value.contains("THIS"))    // false

    if value.contains("UK") == true
        {
         print("Hi")
        }
        else 
        {
        // do your stuff
        }
```

Comment: I tried to do the if Str.containsString(Self.signIn!.text!) but it keeps saying to me ‘Value of type String has no member ‘containsString’

Comment: @UnluckyKitty130 I think you are using Swift 4 . In swift 4 it can be done like this :

var string = "UK"
if string.contains(self.Username!.text!) {
    print("Hi") // checks if your textfield contains "UK"
}

Previous one for the older swift version. Moreover in 
Extension Way
 
extension String {
    func contains(find: String) -> Bool{
        return self.range(of: find) != nil
    }
}

var value = "Hello world" 
print(value.contains("Hello")) // returns true : put value as of your textfield.text
print(value.contains("bo"))    // false